# Add new sheet to existing Excel workbook with VB code

Tags: vba, excel

This code creates an Excel file with one sheet.  This sheet contains the code of an item like (ASR/Floor/Dept./Item_Name/Item_details/1) which I created and works fine, but I want to add a sheet into this Excel file to create another item code, and then save this file.

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim var As Variant
Dim code As String
Dim i, nocode As Integer
Dim fname, heading As String

code = "ASR/" & Text1.Text & "/" & Text2.Text & "/" & Text3.Text & "/" & Text4.Text

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add ' Create a new WorkBook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Specify your worksheet name

nocode = txtnocode.Text
heading = Text6.Text

For i = 2 To nocode + 1
  ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = code & "/" & i - 1 '"ORG"
Next i

fname = "c:\" & Text5.Text & ".xls"

wb.SaveAs (fname)
wb.Close
xlApp.Quit

Set ws = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Worksheets.Add` method is what you are looking for:

```
wb.WorkSheets.Add().Name = "SecondSheet"
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221688%28v=office.11%29.aspx)(scroll down and expand `Sheets and Worksheets`) for the different parameters you can give to `.Add` including being able to add the sheet before or after a specific one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") 
Set ws = wb.Sheets.Add
ws.Activate
```

Answer (score 0):

This is some standard code I use for this type of problem
Note: This code is VBA, to run from within the Excel document itself

```
 Option Explicit

Private m_sNameOfOutPutWorkSheet_1 As String


Sub Delete_Recreate_TheWorkSheet()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    '=========================
    Dim strInFrontOfSheetName As String
    m_sNameOfOutPutWorkSheet_1 = "Dashboard_1"
    strInFrontOfSheetName = "CONTROL"    'create the new worksheet in front of this sheet

    '1] Clean up old data if it is still there
    GetRidOf_WorkSheet_IfItExists (m_sNameOfOutPutWorkSheet_1)

    CreateNewOutputWorkSheet m_sNameOfOutPutWorkSheet_1, strInFrontOfSheetName
    'Color the tab of the new worksheet
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(m_sNameOfOutPutWorkSheet_1).Tab.ColorIndex = 5

    'Select the worksheet that I started with
    Worksheets(strInFrontOfSheetName).Select

    '=========================
      Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
        Select Case Err.Number
            Case Else
                MsgBox "One_Main - Error: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
        End Select
 End Sub

Sub GetRidOf_WorkSheet_IfItExists(sWorkSheetName_ForInitalData As String)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    '=========================

    If fn_WorkSheetExists(sWorkSheetName_ForInitalData) Then
        'Sheet Exists
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Worksheets(sWorkSheetName_ForInitalData).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End If

    '=========================
      Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
        Select Case Err.Number
            Case Else
                MsgBox "GetRidOf_WorkSheet_IfItExists - Error: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
        End Select
    End Sub


Function fn_WorkSheetExists(wsName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    fn_WorkSheetExists = Worksheets(wsName).Name = wsName
End Function


Sub CreateNewOutputWorkSheet(sWorkSheetName_ForOutputData As String, strInFrontOfSheetName As String)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    '=========================
    If fn_WorkSheetExists(sWorkSheetName_ForOutputData) Then
        'Sheet Exists
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Worksheets(sWorkSheetName_ForOutputData).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

    Dim wsX As Worksheet
    Set wsX = Sheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets(strInFrontOfSheetName))

    wsX.Name = sWorkSheetName_ForOutputData

    '=========================
      Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
        Select Case Err.Number
            Case Else
                MsgBox "CreateNewOutputWorkSheet - Error: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
        End Select
End Sub
```